# How to append a value to the end of a url?

Tags: php, string, curl, post, concatenation

My code is

```
$data = array('promoCode' => $_POST["00"]);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$url="http://website.com/promotions/(here)" . $name;
$auth_code = $_POST["auth"];
$name = $_POST["voucher"];
$ch = curl_init();  ;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data_string));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($data_string));   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                        'Authorization:  ' . $auth_code,
                                        'Connection: close'
                                     ));
```

I want to add string after the trailing slash `/` of `http://website.com/promotions/`

I need to add it like `$name = $_POST["voucher"];` to connect it with an html input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the `$name` variable before declaring it. Re-position your `$name` declaration to come before your `$url` declaration like this:

```
$name = $_POST["voucher"];
$url="http://website.com/promotions/" . $name;
```